# Copy all files in folder to another folder prepending a . to the file name and rename it back to original file name

Tags: linux, bash, centos7, file-rename, file-copying

after searching and trying various way I couldn't get it work.

I need to copy lots of files (more than 100 thousand files) to another folder with dot prepended to the file name Example:

/foo/bar/filename1.txt to /foo2/bar/.filename1.txt

and then rename it back to original name /foo2/bar/filename.txt

Why I need to do this is because I have an application that will keep scanning /foo2/bar folder and its sub folder and ignore those file with a dot in front of the file name so that it will not process those file that are copying half way. This mainly because the 2 folder can be in 2 different network drive or some mounted devices.

And i cannot simply use mv or cp because I have some folder that has too many files and it will simply throw argument list too long error thus I have been trying to use find command but to no avail.

Trying out with different command:

```
find /foo/bar/ -type f -exec cp -t /foo2/bar {} +
```

and

```
find /foo/bar/ -type f -exec mv {} /foo2/bar/.{} \;
```

I know the above command won't do what I wanted but that is along the line of what i've tired.

Appreciate anyone that can help...

Comment: Copy the whole structure to `/foo3` and, when finished, rename `/foo3` to `/foo2`. That way, the application that scans `/foo2` won't be fooled by half copied files until the copy is finished and the folder is renamed to its final name.

Comment: I don't think I can do that because /foo2 could be a network drive folder such as samba server

Comment: Can you not tar the files as a .mytar.tar.gz and then just unzip it?

Comment: Do you mean that all files must be copied before the dot is removed? Or that each file can have its dot removed as soon as the copy of that specific file is complete?

Comment: @JL007 which is the problem in being a network drive? You can create `/foo3` in the same network drive and when the copy is finished, just rename that folder. Renaming would be instantaneous.

Comment: Hummm... maybe you mean that `/foo2` would be the mount point of the network drive... in that case, you can create `/foo2/tmp` with read permissions only for you, copy all the information (with final permissions) there and finally move the contents to the root of that folder `/foo2`. Remove the empty `/foo2/tmp` folder and that's all. The lack of read permissions in that folder will prevent the process from reading anything while in progress.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, each file can have its dot removed as soon as the copy of that specific file is complete

Comment: @Poshi Yes /foo2/ would be the mount point, and i'm sorry that i forgot to mention that my application will scan /foo2/ and its sub folder thus placing the file in a tmp folder would not work.

Comment: If the application cannot traverse the `tmp` folder because you explicitly taked away the needed permissions, it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose we have two directories as follows:

```
$ ls -a foo*
foo1:
 .   ..   file1   file2   file3  'file 4'

foo2:
.  ..
```

If we execute next command:

```
$ for file in foo1/* ; do base=$(basename "$file"); cp "foo1/$base" "foo2/.$base"; mv "foo2/.$base" "foo2/$base"; done
```

We will get at the end:

```
$ ls -a foo*
foo1:
.  ..   file1   file2   file3  'file 4'

foo2:
.   ..   file1   file2   file3  'file 4'
```

I think this is what you wanted.

Moreover, the file names with spaces inside will be correctly handled.

Comment: Very good answer, but if I dare to be too nickpicking, it breaks if a filename contains a newline at the end. (Who cares about it? ;)

Comment: @tshiono: LOL. I don't know how many people is even able to create a file with a `\n` in the name, (or with a '/'?).

Comment: Haha, absolutely :)

Comment: OMG! This exactly what I needed and solved my problem. Already tested it out. It is so simple and elegant! Can't believe I didn't thought of it. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: ++ed on behalf of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all files to new dir with the new name:

```
for file in *; do   cp "$file" "./files2//.${file}"; done

$ ls -la ./files2/
total 4
 .
 ..
 .1
 .2
 .3
```

Rename files:

```
cd files2
rename . "" .*
```

output:

```
$ ls -la 
total 4
 .
 ..
 1
 2
 3
```

Comment: I want it to be rename back to original file name immediately after done copying so that it can be processed immediately, I think i forgot to mention it in my question, breaking it up into a few parts is not what I wanted but thanks for helping anyway!!!

Comment: So put the rename inside the loop - I put it as a different step to show you a step-by-step breakdown

Answer (score 0):

Would you try the following:

```
src="/foo/bar"
dest=/foo2/bar"
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    cp -p -- "$src/$f" "$dest/.$f"
    mv -- "$dest/.$f" "$dest/$f"
done < <(find "$src" -type f -printf "%f\0")
```

`-printf "%f\0"` is mostly similar to `-print0` except it strips off the directory name.

Comment: I didn't really try this out but thanks for helping anyway!